# How to include a jQuery and javascript file in a Wordpress page?

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery and javascript code: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

The code runs file in a Wordpress page if I put the code directly in the page: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

But instead of putting code if I call the js file:

```
<script src="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></script>
```

It doesn't work.

I have to put a common jquery and javascript code in many pages. So, I was thinking of putting all code in a js file and calling it from every page instead of copy-paste whole code in every page. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .js file includes opening and closing `<script>` tags in it. This is valid in HTML, but not in JS. Your JS file is likely loading, but is failing on a syntax error because of those tags.

Comment: should I remove <script></script> tag?

Answer (score 0):

let's say you use the twentyfifteen theme:
go to the /wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/functions.php
in the function twentyfifteen_scripts() add this line:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', 'put here the URL of your js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
```